# Allowing headers for pre-flight requests in flask-cors doesn't work

Tags: python, cors, flask-cors

I want to allow 'X-Custom-Field' header for pre-flighted requests. I use flask-cors extension. I don't use `cross_ogirin` decorator. I do it like this:

`CORS(APP, expose_headers=['X-Another'], allow_headers=['X-Custom-Field'])`

But when I test it, `KeyError: 'access-control-allow-headers'` is thrown. But `access-control-expose-headers` is in the response header. My test:

```
self.assertIn('X-Another', headers['access-control-expose-headers'])  # PASSES
self.assertIn('X-Custom-Field', headers['access-control-allow-headers'])  # FAILS
```

On the other hand, when do it manually, test will pass. Like so:

```
@APP.after_request
def add_custom_field_to_headers(response):
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Custom-Field')
  return response
```